# Run sar daily to log file

Tags: logs, sar

How can I run the `sar` command to run daily using cron then get killed every 24 hours and start over again creating a new log file?

Command:

```
sar -u 300 288 >> $(date "+ %Y-%m-%d")-cpu.log
```

This will log usage every 15 minutes for just over 24 hours.

Would this be a proper bash script?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Kill current process
kill sar

# Start new sar
sar -u 300 290 >> $(date "+ %Y-%m-%d")-cpu.log
```

Answer (score 1):

On most linux distros (if not all), `sar` already saves that data in a file in `/var/log...`. Have look at `-o` in `man sar` to find the exact path:

```
    -o [ filename ]
          Save the readings in the file in binary form. Each reading is in a  separate  record.  The  default
          value of the filename parameter is the current daily data file, the /var/log/sysstat/sadd file. The
          -o option is exclusive of the -f option.  All the data available from the kernel are saved  in  the
          file  (in  fact,  sar  calls  its  data collector sadc with the option "-S ALL". See sadc(8) manual
          page).
```

You can read that binary file using `sar -f filename`.

If you really need to take care of the data collection process, check `man sadc`.

Comment: I'm aware of that functionality, however, I need to write to a log file that's human readable for reporting cpu usage.

Comment: @linux then just have `sar >> logfile` executed by `cron` everyday at 23:52.

Comment: Wouldn't it be advisable to kill the process in case it hasn't finished?

Comment: @linguru772x if you running `sar` without _interval_ or _count_, it works more like `cat`. It writes to standard output and terminates, so you have no process to kill... If you're running it with _count_, it will just stop after it finishes counting. Try running `sar` and `sar 2 2` to see the difference.

Comment: so sar -u 900 288 would run from 12:05AM to 12:00AM (next day)  if kicked off at 0 0 * * * in cron?

Comment: @linguru772x 900*288/3600=72 hours, so it would be running from day 1 12:00 AM to day 4 12:00 AM.

Comment: I mean to write 96 instead of 288. That should be 15 min for 96 times.